# Creating dynamic view?

Tags: sql-server, join, dynamic, view

I am working in a database that stores park information in a table.  That table lists park names and  all components of the parks and IDs of the component types.  Something like what is below...

```
"ParkName", "ComponentName", "ComponentID", "ComponentTypeID"
--------------------------------------------------------------
Smith Park, North Slide, 1, 12
Smith Park, South Slide, 2, 12
Smith Park, Swing Set A, 3, 14
Smith Park, Swing Set B, 4, 14
Adams Park, East Slide, 5, 12
Adams Park, West Slide, 6, 12
Adams Park, Swing Set A, 7, 14
Adams Park, Swing Set B, 8, 14
Adams Park, Sandbox A, 9, 15
Adams Park, Sandbox B, 10, 15
```

The attributes of each component type are stored in their own table like the following...

```
dbo.attributes_12
dbo.attributes_14
dbo.attributes_15
```

The attributes in each table are different, but they all have four common fields - "ComponentName", "ComponentID", "Year Constructed" and "Comments"

I did not create this database, however what I'd like to be able to do is create a view
that lists For each Park its components and the attributes of each component.  Something like

```
"ParkName", "ComponentName", "ComponentID", "ComponentTypeID", "Year Constructed", "Comment"
Smith Park, North Slide, 1, 12, 1999, 'Slide Comment 1'
Smith Park, South Slide, 2, 12, 1999, 'Slide Comment 2'
Smith Park, Swing Set A, 3, 14, 2006, 'Swing Set Comment 1'
Smith Park, Swing Set B, 4, 14, 2008, 'Swing Set Comment 2'
Adams Park, East Slide, 5, 12, 2006, 'Needs Repair'
Adams Park, West Slide, 6, 12, 2004, 'Ladder is broken'
Adams Park, Swing Set A, 7, 14, 2009, 'in good shape'
Adams Park, Swing Set B, 8, 14, 2010, 'chain needs replacing'
Adams Park, Sandbox A, 9, 15, 2001, 'needs new sand'
Adams Park, Sandbox B, 10, 15, 2002, 'in good shape'
```

Is there a "dynamic" way to do this?

What I'm struggling with is how to join the various attribute tables without manually adding them (ie through some sort of SQL code).  There can be many types of components in a park beyond swing sets and slides (ie lights, benches, ponds, ornamental trees, garbage cans, signs, etc) and manually adding all the attribute tables to a view could become somewhat cumbersome and not necessarily efficient especially if a new type of component was added.

I'm hoping someone can provide some suggestions, but maybe what I'm trying to do isn't possible.

Carl

Comment: Well, if you are using SQL server, you could create a function that gets YearConstructed, and one that gets Comments, and include them in a view, but I'm pretty sure that manually coding the joins in the view will perform better, even if it does get to be rather large.

Comment: Too bad you have such a bad database design. There is no easy way to get data like this when you use EAV tables. If you want this stuff, don't use a relational datbase use a nosql database that is at least designed to work with this kind of unstructured information. If stuck with it, then you shoud pull it in a relational way and pivot in the front end. And never use an EAV table again, do your due diligence and design your database instead of using this cop out technique.

Comment: OK- Thanks for the input.  I'll try creating a couple of functions and see how it goes.